# Is there a way to contruct this kind of result using group by in sql?

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot

I have a table which consists of data where in I'm having trouble counting the corresponding rows.

Here is the sample table:

[image]

I am expecting an output like this:

[image]

Comment: You need "conditional aggregation".

Comment: Next time please paste your data as text, not as images, and tag your request with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    sum(case when result = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) count_x,
    sum(case when result is null then 1 else 0 end) count_blank
from mytable
```

I assume that by *blank* you mean *null*. If not, then you can change the condition in the second `sum()` from `result is null` to `result = ''`.

If you are running MySQL, this can be shortened a little:

```
select
    sum(result = 'X') count_x,
    sum(result is null) count_blank
from mytable
```